# Most stable way to handle resizing of UIView?

Tags: ios, event-handling, uikit, resize

There are many geometric related properties on `UIView`.

- `frame`
- `bounds`
- `transform`

Maybe more.

If I want to execute some behavior when the view is resized, what should I do?

I usually tried overriding `-layoutSubviews` method, but it also be called by non-resizing event. Even I override all of the properties, I still can't sure I have handled all of possibilities.

What's most stable and recommended way to handle resize event?

Answer (score 3):

In *Swift*, you can do:

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually don't override `layoutSubviews` for resize, exactly because of what you said. I write my own `layoutSubviewz` and call it whenever it's needed, e.g. I override `setFrame` like this:

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  [super setFrame:frame];
  [self layoutSubviewz];
}
```

Comment: I used this in Xamarin: public override CGRect Frame
        {
            get { return base.Frame; }
            set
            {
                MyCustomMethod(value);
                base.Frame = value;
            }
        }